# Changing bitmaps on a canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have a view class and and activity and the view class in linked in with the XML. The view class starts by drawing a bitmap of the letter a. In the activity there are next and previous buttons to allow the user to maneuver through the letter images. However I have looked everywhere for clearing a canvas and there doesn't seem to be anything on the matter. I am unsure how to access the view class to change the images as they are linked through the XML layout file.

View class

```
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    drawLetterA(canvas);

}

public void drawLetterA (Canvas canvas) {

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lettera);
    canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

}

public void drawLetterB (Canvas canvas) {

    //canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.letterb);
    canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

}
```

Comment: what didn't you like about your .drawColor solution?

Comment: When I tried to access  the drawLetterB function from my activity class it was saying that the class was bloated